# Why does freshly cut grass smell like a watermelon?

Tags: botany, olfaction

I found that, when I smell watermelon aroma outdoors, someone nearby has mowed  the grass. Is there an underlying basis?

Comment: I can't say I've ever experienced that, but a cursory Google search indicates this is not unheard of.  Also, a weird Harry Potter fanfic.

Comment: Are you saying that when grass is mowed, you smell watermelons, or that when you smell watermelons, someone has cut grass near you?

Comment: I meant that the aroma of the freshly cut grass is like a watermelon smell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

[cis-3-hexenal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cis-3-Hexenal) is probably the main reason.  It is one of the main chemicals in fresh-cut grass smell (lots of references besides wiki if you google it).  [This](https://www.ideals.illinois.edu/bitstream/handle/2142/16898/2_Genthner_Elizabeth.pdf) fairly comprehensive paper on watermelon odorants also says that they find a lot of cis-3-hexenal in fresh cut watermelon.  See tables 3.1, 3.2 and 3.3.

Comment: Is this chemical a [GLV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_leaf_volatiles) (Green Leaf Volatiles)

Comment: i think so, you can see cis-3-hexenal in this reference on the GLV wiki page: http://www.olfacts.nl/index_bestanden/Page7.htm